# Failed to start nanoexpress server

Tags: javascript, nanoexpress

I want to rewrite my AWS Lambda functions to a standalone machine. While I was reading about NodeJS Express I found new library called [nanoexpress](https://nanoexpress.js.org/support/faq) which [excels in performance](https://github.com/the-benchmarker/web-frameworks). I downloaded an example code and saved it locally.

```
import nanoexpress from 'nanoexpress';
const app = nanoexpress();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send({ status: 'ok' });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

But there is no information how to start it. I thought it will be similar to NodeJS but it fails:

```
node server.js
(node:6944) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
C:\dev\mezinamiridici\infrastructure\src\server.js:1
import nanoexpress from 'nanoexpress';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

How shall I start the server?

Comment: Try using CommonJS variant like `const nanoexpress = require('nanoexpress')` or read more about Node.js ES Modules. I see you new to Node.js, but i sure you can learn and run your server

Comment: this variant is working, please update the answer

Comment: Updated, i see you marked as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use CommonJS variant like [this](https://github.com/nanoexpress/nanoexpress/blob/master/examples/basic.js)

```js
const nanoexpress = require('nanoexpress');

const app = nanoexpress();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.end('hello world');
});

app.listen(4000);
```

or

Try add `"type": "module"` field like [this](https://github.com/nanoexpress/pro-slim/blob/master/package.json#L5).
As well as don't forget, Node.js version should be at least v12.6+ for using ES Modules and requires additional `--experimental-modules` runtime argument to be working properly as mentioned [here](https://nanoexpress.js.org/#installation). For example, `node --experimental-modules server.js`

I think with these modifications your first server should start and work.

Comment: If with this answer your issue was solved, please don't forget to check this answer as Solution. Thanks

Comment: There is the same behaviour in nanoexpress-dev-env sample repository where the module is defined in package.json.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest Node 13 version so I do not need these extra parameters, do I?

Comment: I check `nanoexpress-dev-env` later, but issue should not happen as there `rollup` does thing for us.

Comment: Yes, in Node 13.6+ extra arguments does not need

Comment: On `nanoexpress-dev-env` you have two ways to run (combo): `npm run build + npm run start` or `npm run dev + npm run start:dev` for local dev with hot-reload with `nodemon`

Comment: Windows: 'rollup' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209677/discussion-between-leos-literak-and-dalisoft).